# How to check if a String contains a digit?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to check if a string contain a digit in jsp  .I know how to do this in java but don't know how to do this in jsp ?
Can anyone help me?

```
firstNumber.matches("[0-9]{1,13}(\\.[0-9]*)?")
```

Comment: Contains a digit? `firstNumber.matches(".*[0-9].*")`. Your expression will only work if entire value is 1-13 digits, and an optional decimal point followed by unlimited number of digits. That would be called "value is a [decimal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal)" (excluding negative numbers).

Comment: @Andreas how can i wirte this statment in jsp?

Comment: Sure. Your version: `<c:if test="${firstNumber.matches(&quot;[0-9]{1,13}(\\.[0-9]*)?&quot;)}">`

Comment: Once again, your expression and BiscuitBoys answer _do not check_ if the string _contains_ a digit — they check if the entire string is all digits. @Andreas `.*[0-9].*` matches anything as long as _there is at least one digit_ in the string, which is what _"String contains a digit"_ means.

Comment: @StephenP - Yes. I have updated the answer. Probably an example string from OP could have helped...

Answer (score 2):

JSP *is* Java (more or less):

```
<% if (firstNumber.matches(".*[0-9].*")) {
       // do something
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Expression Language constructs?

```
   <c:set var="myValue">${firstNumber}</c:set>
    <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${myValue.matches('.*[0-9].*')}">
        ${var} contains number!
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
        <!--do something-->
       </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this to check:

```
 <c:if test='${firstNumber.matches(".*[0-9].*")}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to find out if the String contains a number. Take a look at the matches() method

```
<%@ page import="java.util.regex.*" %>

<% if(firstNumber.matches(".*\\d.*")){
   // contains a number
  } %>
```